# Which ports do I use to send get requests for a full-stack Vue/Flask/MongoDB project?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, vuejs2, pymongo

I've built a mongo database and a Python/PyMongo/Flask script. Now I'm learning Vue so I can put that data on a webpage, but I'm having trouble understanding which ports to use in my path. I understand mongodb uses 27017, Flask uses 5000, and Vue uses 8080.

Here's my Python/PyMongo/Flask script (app.py). Since I can't give you the entire database data, I altered the 'findNames' function to just return a string.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from pymongo import MongoClient


DEBUG = True

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.argodb

CORS(app)


@app.route('/searchDB', methods=['GET'])
def findNames():
    return jsonify('The database is connected!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And on the client side, here's my Vue index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import searchDB from '@/components/searchDB';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/searchDB',
      component: searchDB,
    },
  ],
});
```

Here's the main component, App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

And here's my component, searchDB.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="search-db">
    <h1>Database Search</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'searchDB',
  data() {
    return {
      msg: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getMessage() {
      const path = 'http://localhost:5000/searchDB';
      axios.get(path)
        .then((res) => {
          this.msg = res.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.error(error);
        });
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.getMessage();
  },
};
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: You're more or less free to use whichever ports you want as long as they don't interfere with any other applications running on those ports. Are you running into any errors with what you have set up?

Comment: Yes. I can't connect my mongodb to my Vue instance. My Vue isn't consuming the Flask/Mongo data that I've parsed (in this case, the string that is returned).

Comment: Just so I'm crystal on this, when I run 'npm run dev' on my client-side Vue API (the Vue index.html), I'm using Axios to send a 'get' request. After that, I'm not sure what happens. Does my request go through Flask (port 5000) first? Or does it go to mongodb (port 27017)? Or both?

Answer (score 1):

You have each application running on its own port -- MongoDB running on 27017, Flask running on 5000 and Vue (npm) running on 8080. The chain of events that you'd ideally like to happen is this.

1. Vue uses axios to send an http request to Flask on port 5000
2. Flask receives the request and handles the request and recognizes that it needs to retrieve data from the database before sending a response, so it submits a query to Mongo which is running on port 27017.
3. Mongo returns the requested data to Flask
4. Flask formats the data into an appropriate http response and returns it to the requester (Vue)
5. The axios call receives its response and reacts to the response data, storing the data if the response was successful (e.g. status code 200 for a Get)

Since there are a lot of steps along the way that need to go correctly, it's a good idea to test in small pieces first to ensure the whole chain is working properly. I would suggest:

1. Test to ensure Flask is connecting to Mongo properly and can retrieve data
2. Next use a curl statement or Postman to check to see if your Flask webserver is handling calls to http://localhost:5000/searchDB properly. Note that if you can also take Mongo out of the equation (as you have done) for this test by just having the call return a string.
3. Once you are sure you can make calls to that endpoint (/searchDB) successfully, then you can start testing Vue and Axios. This is where you are likely to run into CORS issues.

*If you are able to get everything working but cannot resolve the CORS issues*, then another possible setup would be to stick NGINX in front of Flask and Vue. This solution involves running NGINX on its own port, let's say port 3000 and then configuring the server to proxy for ports 5000 and 8080. Then you would change your Vue/Axios code to make calls to port 3000 instead of port 5000, which avoids CORS since this would then be the same port that Vue is being served on through NGINX.